# Hidden form values not binding on Form POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, model-binding

I am sending a List to the view.
Trying to submit each item in the list through a form.

**Model:**

```
 public partial class Model
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UId { get; set; }
        public int WId { get; set; }
        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

        public virtual AspNetUsers User { get; set; }
        public virtual WModel W { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult UWC()
{
    List<Model> uW = db.UW.Include(x => x.U).Include(x=>x.W).ToList();
    return View(uW);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UWC(Model uW)
{
    var s = ModelState.ErrorCount;
    return RedirectToAction("UWC");
}
```

**View**

```
@model List<Model>
            <table  class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].W.Name)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].W.Type)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].W.Description)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].W.IsActive)
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @for (var item = 0; item < Model.Count(); item++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[item].W.Name)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[item].W.Type)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[item].W.Description)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @if (Model[item].IsEnabled)
                                {
                                    @try
                                    {
                                        <form asp-action="UWC" asp-controller="UM" method="post">
                                            <div class="switch switch--horizontal switch--no-label ">
                                                <input asp-for="@Model[item].IsEnabled" type="radio" value="@Model[item].IsEnabled" class="form-control" />
                                                <input asp-for="@Model[item].IsEnabled" type="radio" value="false" class="form-control" />
                                                <span class="toggle-outside"><span class="toggle-inside"></span></span>
                                            </div>

                                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[item].Id" value="@Model[item].Id" />
                                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[item].WId" value="@Model[item].WId" />
                                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[item].UId" value="@Model[item].UId" />

                                        </form>
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e)
                                    {
                                        var s = e.Message;
                                    }
                                }
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('input[type=radio]').change(function () {
                $(this).closest('form').submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

The above is the complete code.

**When I submit the form using radio button toggle, only the IsEnabled property is getting bound on POST.**

But the page source shows that all the properties are being properly bound in the view i.e Id,Uid,Wid all these properties have been replaced by their values.

@Model[item].Id is not necessarily in sequence, but I believe item - the loop variable determines model binding.

**When the Page source has the model values, why is it not being reflected on POST?

If model binding is breaking, how come the IsEnabled property is being bound correctly?**

Comment: the model that's sent to the view is a List of models.  Your form is posting a singular model.

Comment: @pcalkins: Ack. This code is very confusing. The OP is actually only posting one `Model`. Each iteration is a separate form.

Comment: @ChrisPratt tried the above but this results in no binding, I get a List with no items,

Comment: post your constructor... the controller code is incomplete.

Comment: I am posting a List<model> to the view, in each iteration over the List I am using a form to POST the List item .i.e model to  a controller action.

Comment: if you are trying to post only one model, bind one.  If you want them all posted at once, you need to include them in the same <form>...</form>  I can't tell which you are trying to do without the constructor.

Comment: if you're trying to post the full list, you'll probably need @Html.HiddenFor for id/index.

Comment: @pcalkins I am using the list to populate a table, one of whose fields is a bool. When the bool is triggered I am posting that particular item to the controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199206/discussion-between-abhilash-gopalakrishna-and-pcalkins).

Comment: @ChrisPratt  I am using the list to populate a table, one of whose fields is a bool. When the bool is triggered I am posting that particular item to the controller.
How can I change my code? :)
My idea is once the model has binded me posting it in a separate iteration will bind it.

Comment: Post the full controller.  Do you have any "[BindProperty]" tags?  Right now you are passing the class to the method.  If you bind you won't have to do that.

Comment: @pcalkins nope not using bind properties. Will create a fiddle and post the link :)

Comment: you're going to have different ids on the form inputs... It'll have an index because the view model is a list.  Bools/checkboxes/radio buttons are pretty quirky in asp.net, and I think it just defaults to false even when there is no value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I submit the form using radio button toggle, only the IsEnabled property is getting bound on POST.

The `false` value of `IsEnable` property is not passed by model binding but the default value for `bool`.

> When the Page source has the model values, why is it not being reflected on POST?

I reproduce your problem and you need to specify the `name` attribute for the input to correspond to the argument `Model` 's properties on your action. Otherwise model binding will not work in your situation.

```
@try
{
    <form asp-action="UWTest" asp-controller="Test" method="post">
        <div class="switch switch--horizontal switch--no-label ">
            <input asp-for="@Model[item].IsEnabled" type="radio" name="IsEnabled" value="@Model[item].IsEnabled" class="form-control" />
            <input asp-for="@Model[item].IsEnabled" type="radio" name="IsEnabled" value="false" class="form-control" />
            <span class="toggle-outside"><span class="toggle-inside"></span></span>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[item].Id" value="@Model[item].Id" name="Id"/>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[item].WId" value="@Model[item].WId" name="WId"/>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[item].UId" value="@Model[item].UId" name="UId" />

    </form>
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    var s = e.Message;
}
```

Comment: The above works!!
But, the radio button value is always false.
However, I serialized the form using jquery and the radio inputs are binding properly i.e - true when true and false when false.